# Disabled textarea

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The textarea is disabled but I still want to be able to scroll down and see everything.

**It works well on Chrome but on IE (Internet Explorer) it does not.** Is there a way to fix this??

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<textarea disabled>Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello World</textarea>
```

Comment: It does work in Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: @dmitri7 It does not work. I have IE 11 and I am not able to scroll. If I try to scroll, it scrolls the page. My version is 11.418. I mean scroll with the mouse wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `readonly` instead.

Because you could move the scroll to a wrapping element, but IE has another issue where it will scroll the body at the same time as you scrolling the element which requires javascript hacks to fix afaik.

```css
textarea {
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

/* Simulate disabled look how you please */
textarea[readonly="true"] {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<textarea readonly="true">Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldWorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello WorldHello World Hello World</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of **disabled** use **readonly** attribute.

Comment: And add some styling to simulate the "disabled" look.

Answer (score 0):

In wich version of IE? It's actually working fine on IE11... maybe you should verify the version you are running.

Answer (score 0):

With IE11 you can use the disabled looking Scroll Buttons not the Mouse Wheel

Comment: Does this answer *really* add anything to the information provided by the others?